# Should I be able to replace the BC547 with a 2N2222A in this circuit?

Tags: transistors, bjt, datasheet, maximum-ratings

I am working through a particular [Instructable to build a simple AC current detector](https://www.instructables.com/Wireless-AC-Current-Detector/).
Just a hobbyist circuit...
[image: instructable pic]

Unfortunately the Instructable doesn't include a schematic so I've recreated here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQt04h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Replacing the BC547**

I don't have a BC547, but I do  have a 2N2222A.  Both are NPN BJTs.

[The BC547 datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/11551/ONSEMI/BC547.html) shows the following:

[image: bc547 datasheet]

When I compare the data to my 2N2222A (with my limited knowledge), it looks as though I should be able to "safely" replace the BC547 with the 2N2222A.

[image: 2N2222A]

Does it look like the max ranges of the 2N2222A should be able to handle this circuit?

Comment: At least at first glance, I don't see anything that says it's likely to release the magic smoke, but it may not work as well--the 2n2222 has noticeably lower rated hfe.

Comment: You need to look at the gains between the two. Beta or Hfe.

Comment: As others have noted, the current gain is lower so the Darlington gain may be quite a bit less, as it's the product of the two gains (sort-of the square of the hFE if it was constant over Ic). You probably know this, but also the pinout is different.

Comment: I've seen the 2N3904 suggested as an equivalent, if you want to find its datasheet.

Comment: Thanks all, I will also make a comparison on the hfe.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for suggestion of a possible replacement.  I will check out the 2N3904. I think i may some of those.

Comment: I used 2n2222 in this circuit - works normally. Even if hfe is a bit different in datasheet, there is huge variation of hfe between individual devices

Comment: @fifi_22 Thanks for letting me know. I'll try the circuit out with my 2n2222 also.